# Mongodb if statement

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I want to update one field based on variable passed dropData(either true or false)

```
const updateResponse = await quiz.updateOne(
              { user: ObjectId(user._id), _id: ObjectId(questionId)},
                [{ $set: { 
                    answers: answers, 
                    correctAnswer: correctAnswer,
                    question: question,
                    description: description,
                    category: category,  
                    answersFromUsers: {
                        $cond: {
                          if: {
                            dropData 
                          },
                          then: [], 
                          else: '$answersFromUsers', 
                        }
                    }
                } }],        
            )
```

however field answersFromUsers is always changed to empty array even when dropData is false.

Comment: Try to add the condition without brackets `if: dropData,`

Comment: Thanks, that seems to do the work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[$cond (aggregation)](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/#-cond--aggregation-)

Evaluates a boolean expression to return one of the two specified return expressions.

`{ $cond: { if: <boolean-expression>, then: <true-case>, else: <false-case> } }`

when you add brackets in `<boolean-expression>` mongoDB will look for an [expression operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/#expression-operators), but in your case you just need to add the bollean:

```js
$cond: {
 if: dropData,
 then: [], 
 else: '$answersFromUsers', 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the values before sending the query there is no need to do the condition in the database with MQL.

You can do it before sending the query like

```js
var answersFromUsers;
if(dropData) answersFromUsers=[];
else answersFromUsers='$answersFromUsers';

const updateResponse = await quiz.updateOne(
              { user: ObjectId(user._id), _id: ObjectId(questionId)},
                [{ $set: { 
                    answers: answers, 
                    correctAnswer: correctAnswer,
                    question: question,
                    description: description,
                    category: category,  
                    answersFromUsers: answersFromUsers,
                } }],        
            )
```

In case you didn't know the values before sending the query you could do it on server like this

```json
{
  "$set": {
    ...otherfields...
    "answersFromUsers": {
      "$cond": [
        dropData,      //your javascript variable
        [],
        "$answersFromUsers"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for anwser, i tried to use ternary operator to set answersFromUsers but i didnt use "" around $answersFromUsers and it didnt work, best solution is answersFromUsers: dropData ? [] : "$answersFromUsers", no need for extra variable and if before.

Comment: The above code will work, you dont need to do it on database but its fine if you do also.
In general if you can do something before sending the query its best to do it before.
`$cond` has 2 syntaxes i sended the most concise(without the if else), both are fine.